# python installing pywinauto on 64 bit

Tags: python, installation, pywinauto

I am trying to install pywinauto on my 64 bit machine. I have dealt with the issues with the Assertion error and removed them from the win32structures file. However now when I go to import pywinauto i get this error:

```
>>> import pywinauto
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
import findwindows
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 37, in <module>
import controls
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\__init__.py", line 25,
in <module>
    from HwndWrapper import GetDialogPropsFromHandle
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\HwndWrapper.py", line 34, in    <module>
    from pywinauto import SendKeysCtypes as SendKeys
ImportError: cannot import name SendKeysCtypes
```

does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known pywinauto problem. Use a chain - python(32bit) + pywinauto on your 64bit system.

Comment: Yes. The correct way. I uninstall 64bit python and installed 32bit version. This problem solved.